# Permission Denied while mounting a folder as NFS and CIFS (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, nfs, cifs

I am trying to mount a folder "media" over the network as a nfs and cifs share by doing this.

At the Server side configuration of  "/etc/exports"

```
/export/bins            *(rw,fsid=0,nohide,no_subtree_check,sync)
/export/bins/media       *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

At the Client side (System 1)

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 192.168.1.45:/media /mnt/mediaMountedNFS
```

At the Client side (System 2)

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.45/media /mnt/mediaMountedCIFS -o username=kevin,password=pass1234
```

#

Scenario:

Create a folder "temp" from Server on "media" not accessible form "mediaMountedNfs",after the mount has occured.

media/temp --- > X ----> mediaMountedNfs/temp, cannot add or delete contents, Permission denied at the mediaMountedNfs/temp.

Solution : manually use

```
chown -R kevin:somegroup temp
```

Error Details : Permission Denied.  Have to manually change the folder permissions every time I create a folder on the "media" folder.  Occurs only with respect to the NFS.

Any way i can set the gid / uid of the folder and the sub folder to a specific value while being NFS shared? Or an solution to this ?

Comment: Your question is not clear: did you install/configure anything on the server side for samba? If not, you cannot mount a CIFS directory.

Comment: Samba works fine. Mentioned it because that fodler is also being shared as  a cifs share.(can provide samba conf details if that is relevant).